# Efficiently bin data in python

Tags: python, pandas, performance, loops, group-by

I am trying to summarise a database of activity times by user id to give an array of  event count per timeslot to show a summary of weekly behaviour. I have approx. 35k ids over 3M events covering 2y of time in a pandas dataframe. I have two event time columns and I want to combine them into the same output array.

A sample of the true data, included in case I'm missing something or asking the wrong question.

```
print(data)
    id                  startTime                   endTime
0   633597028911259693  2021-01-13 06:25:00+00:00   2021-01-13 06:56:00+00:00
1   633597028910043601  2021-01-13 06:58:00+00:00   2021-01-13 08:05:00+00:00
2   633597028909606343  2021-01-13 07:07:00+00:00   2021-01-13 07:46:00+00:00
3   633597028910076221  2021-01-13 07:56:00+00:00   2021-01-13 09:02:00+00:00
4   633597028911248563  2021-01-13 08:09:00+00:00   2021-01-13 08:41:00+00:00
5   633597028910169505  2021-01-13 08:36:00+00:00   2021-01-13 09:11:00+00:00
6   633597028910980570  2021-01-13 08:53:00+00:00   2021-01-13 09:06:00+00:00
7   633597028910039724  2021-01-13 11:29:00+00:00   2021-01-13 12:26:00+00:00
8   633597028910980570  2021-01-13 15:15:00+00:00   2021-01-13 15:32:00+00:00
9   633597028911259693  2021-01-13 15:31:00+00:00   2021-01-13 15:54:00+00:00
10  633597028910043601  2021-01-13 16:31:00+00:00   2021-01-13 17:32:00+00:00
11  633597028911248563  2021-01-13 17:06:00+00:00   2021-01-13 17:40:00+00:00
12  633597028909606343  2021-01-13 17:21:00+00:00   2021-01-13 17:55:00+00:00
13  633597028910039724  2021-01-13 17:29:00+00:00   2021-01-13 18:21:00+00:00
14  633597028910076221  2021-01-13 17:58:00+00:00   2021-01-13 19:06:00+00:00
15  633597028910169505  2021-01-13 18:00:00+00:00   2021-01-13 18:10:00+00:00
16  633597028910169505  2021-01-13 18:12:00+00:00   2021-01-13 18:33:00+00:00
17  633597028911259693  2021-01-14 06:18:00+00:00   2021-01-14 06:56:00+00:00
18  633597028907641698  2021-01-14 06:51:00+00:00   2021-01-14 07:49:00+00:00
19  633597028910960846  2021-01-14 07:19:00+00:00   2021-01-14 08:27:00+00:00
```

Preprocessing of my data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import timedelta

timeslot_minutes=60
data['startSlot'] = ((data.startTime - data.startTime.dt.floor('7D')) / timedelta(minutes=timeslot_minutes)).fillna(0).astype(int)
data['endSlot'] = ((data.endTime - journeys.endTime.dt.floor('7D')) / timedelta(minutes=timeslot_minutes)).fillna(0).astype(int)

slots = pd.concat([data.set_index('isrn').startSlot, data.set_index('isrn').endSlot], axis=0)
```

To generate equivalent data (this is evenly distributed, my data is not):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

ids = np.random.randint(6335*1000, 6435*1000, 35000)
timeslots = np.arange(168) # 168 hour long timeslots per week
data = {'id':np.random.choice(ids, 3*10**6),
        'timeslot':np.random.choice(timeslots, 3*10**6),
        }
data = pd.DataFrame(data).set_index('id')
```

My attempt so far but this takes a million years:

```
grps = data.groupby('id')
output = {}
for id,grp in grps:
    output[id] = [grp[grp.timeslot==slot].shape[0] for slot in timeslots]
output = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(output)
```

and this also takes long and gives me a far higher count in the 0 timeslot than expected:

```
grps = data.groupby('id')
output2 = {id:[sum([slot==event for event in times.values]) for slot in timeslots] for id,times in grps}
output2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(output2)
```

Expected output something like:

```
id          0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   ... 158 159 160 161 162 163 164 165 166 167
63350242    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
63379701    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0
63449716    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0
63391102    0   0   0   0   0   0   2   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   2   0   0   0   0   0
63352305    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

I feel like I'm missing some obvious numpy or pandas functions for this. Current speeds have been between 18m and 90m for the run. Any help appreciated!

Comment: You're spinning over the list for each grouping? That seems excessive.

Comment: Indeed. I know I'm doing something daft but I cannot see my way past it

Comment: I think you might be able to do your aggregate function without looping over your whole list using `apply()` in conjunction with a `lambda` function right after your `groupby()` function.

Comment: Urgh. I was just working on that.  I imagine it will speed up somewhat, but it does not feel pythonic.

Comment: `timeslot_minutes` is not defined?

Comment: Additionally, your expected output and reference input have nothing to do with each other; the set of IDs in each is disjoint.

Comment: If you can, kindly share a small reproducible sample with expected output.

Comment: I have amended the reference answer. Sorry - in my haste and frustration I copy pasta'd the wrong output from my notebook. The true sample & preprocessing is now complete. The equivalent data for reproduction matches the example output too I  think (it is handwritten but should be right).

Answer (score 1):

You are missing numpy broadcasting.

```py
# Data Generation. We will use a small value for n so that the original
# algorithm can run quickly
n = 10

ids = np.random.randint(6335 * 1000, 6435 * 1000, 35000)
timeslots = np.arange(168)

data = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "id": np.random.choice(ids, 3 * n),
        "timeslot": np.random.choice(timeslots, 3 * n),
    }
).set_index("id")

# Original algorithm
grps = data.groupby("id")
output = {}

for id, grp in grps:
    output[id] = [grp[grp.timeslot == slot].shape[0] for slot in timeslots]
output1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(output)

# Using numpy broadcasting
output2 = (
    pd.DataFrame(
        timeslots[:, None] == data["timeslot"].to_numpy(),  # the broadcasting
        columns=data.index,
    )
    .groupby(data.index, axis=1)
    .sum()
)

# Assert that they produce the same output
assert output1.equals(output2)
```

The numpy broadcasting algorithm can finish in ~5s with `n = 1_000_000`. The disadvantage of this method is memory consumption: it takes `len(timeslots) * len(data) * 8` bytes of memory to perform the broadcasting. Python crashed on my computer when `n = 10_000_000`. There are ways to mitigate that if your problem grows that big.

Comment: Please help me understand - I've managed to avoid delving back into matrix maths generally so numpy has remained an occasional tool mostly avoided. I guess this works because if I have a 2D array x (with 168 rows and None columns) and a 1D array y, doing x==y produces an x*y sized boolean array? This is helpful stuff

Comment: I've just looked  it up myself. I had no really focussed on this before. Cheers! https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html